# How to automate svn check-in in cruisecontrol?

Tags: checkin

I have cc.net configured to automatically checkout build,unit test and version a given branch on svn.. but how do i automate check-in the source back into an svn tag together with the versioning information (assemblyinfo.cs,corresponding version info on the sourcecode) ?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer posted at [Cruisecontrol.net submit a file to SVN after a task has changed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296616/cruisecontrol-net-submit-a-file-to-svn-after-a-task-has-changed-it/4187517#4187517)